# MySQL Trigger to update value after 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

Hey guys does anyone know how I can change the value of a field in my database (MySQL) through a trigger, I'm using phpMyAdmin.

I want to change the value of the online field to 0 after 5 minutes, when the value is 1 a timer is automatically started and after 5 minutes the value is changed to 0.
Sorry for this terrible English, Portuguese is my main Language :)

[Table Utilizador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pze6s.png)

Comment: It will be easier to just have a `last_active` timestamp field which you update at every activity, and display the user as offline if they were last active more than 5 min ago (`last_active < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINTUE)` )

Comment: Trigger cannot. Event procedure may. But the trigger may create this event procedure.